# How to disable the low storage notification sound on a Windows 10 phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, notifications, sound

As the title says, I want to disable the sound for the low storage notification on my Windows 10 phone (Lumia).

**EDIT**: I don't know why someone removed my comment here. It expressed how stupid and annoying this feature (the sound notification) is. It's important to state things like this.

Comment: You can disable sound for system alerts in Settings -> Audio. Is this what you wanted? There is also a Storage option in manage app audio (not sure if translations are right though, my phone is not in English).

Comment: Why is it important to express how annoying something is? It doesn't relate to what you've done to try and solve the problem, and it's worth remembering your audience is other users of the devices, and not a paid support team that can influence product design.